# Accessing variables in parent function

Tags: r, closures, global-variables, r-s4

I'm working on a script that finds text in large PDFs, and I have the bare bones script written out. I'm trying to refactor my code to encapsulate the main while loop in a function, so I can run `sapply()` on it with a list of the PDFs. Some of the functions that I call within the main loop require values from that main loop: here's a stripped down, pseudo-version of my code:

```
pdfParse <- function() {
  N <- sample(1:50, 1)*2
  n = N/2; i = 0   

  while (i <= N) {
    what <- whatP(n)
    i = i + length(what)
    if !length(what) {break}
    else {n <- N/2 - i}
  }
  n
}

res <- sample(0:1, N)
r = 1
whatP <- function(t) {
  r = r*2
  if (t%%3) {
    if (t%%5) {
      return(res[(n/r):n])
    } else {
      whatP((rev(t)[1]):(rev(t)[1] + r))
  } else {return(rep(NaN, 2))}
}
```

So my question is, how do I access the variable `n` that I've defined in the `pdfParse` function within the function it calls? Even if it's possible, I'd like to avoid assigning it as a global variable. I've read a bit into closures, but I'm not sure if that's an applicable solution here.

Edit: For clarification, `whatP(n)` starts out with `n` as its initial argument, but it's recursive, so depending on whether certain conditions are fulfilled, it may end up operating on a vector that doesn't even include `n`. but I still want to return the something that depends on the original `n` I defined in `pdfParse`

Comment: How is it accessed within functions that are called FROM WITHIN the function? Isn't it just accessed because your function call is `whatP(n)`?

Comment: From what I see here, you call `whatP(n)` in `pdfParse`.  Then in your `whatP` function, change `n` to `t`.  That should fix your issue.

Comment: hmm, maybe this wasn't the best condensation of my code.

`whatP(n)` starts out with `n` as its initial argument, but it's recursive, so depending on whether certain conditions are fulfilled, it may end up operating on a vector that doesn't even include `n`. but I still want to return the something that depends on the original `n` I defined in `pdfParse`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Your `pdfParse ` function has a syntax error in the `if` statement and `N` is not defined.

Comment: Why does this question have the [s4] tag? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with S4.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and probably safest, given that your `res` function is recursive) is to make `n` an *argument* of `whatP`.

```
whatP <- function(t,n) {
...
}
```

and then call it from `pdfParse` with two arguments instead of one.

If for some reason you don't want to do this, then you have two options

(a) you can actually just use `n` as though it were in scope. R's rules for where it looks for a variable are very different from, say, C(++). In order, R searches in

- the environment of the current function
- the environment of its parent (the function that called it)
- the environment of its parent's parent and so on
- the global environment
- the environments of loaded packages, in the same order they appear in `search()`.

Since your function is being called from within the function that defined `n`, it will find the appropriate value under the second (or third, given it's recursive) bullet.

(b) you can use `get` with a suitable (negative) value of `pos`, corresponding to the parent. (Alternatively, use `sys.frame`). Not recommended here as it's tricky to get right with recursive functions, but can be useful in other situations (and it will bypass any `n` you might have redefined in the meantime in another, closer, scope).